# Google maps inside hidden menu

Tags: html, css, google-maps, drop-down-menu

i have a weird issue - i have a dropdown menu, which is triggered by hover. The elements are Google maps and two submenus with a content. When hovering above the menu labels, dropdowns work fine. But when hovering with cursor on a empty space below the menu, Google maps becomes visible. I've tried to setup `z-index` accordingly but it doesn't help.

Demo jsfiddle: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8r4j7wt/2/)

I would like to keep the menu html/css only so any help without javascript solution is appriciated, thanks.

Edit: can't use display: property to hide the map and show it again as i need the menu to be transitioned with css3.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q8r4j7wt/1/ just try this out

Comment: thanks, i forgot to mention that i can't use display: none/block as i need only opacity and visiblity so i can transition the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using *visibility* and *opacity* to hide them. This means that the elements are where you positioned them, you just can't see them.

So they receive the full range of mouse events.

You need to position them off the page and bring them back in when you want to show them.

```
.item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    left: -999em;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    background: #eee;
}
.menu .nav:hover .item {
    opacity: 1;
    left:0;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/q8r4j7wt/3/